WinForms MDI child keeps stealing focus
I am writing a WinForms MDI application in .NET 8.
Its purpose is to allow users to view and edit multiple relational database schemas.
There is only one MDI form in the application hosting multiple child forms.
// The main MDI parent.
public class FormMain: Form { }
// All MDI child forms except ONE are of the following type.
public class FormModelEditor: Form { }

There is one child form that is given special treatment (which also seems to be the problematic one). This form is responsible for displaying a list of available schemas and is loaded at the start of the application and stays open as an MDI child till the parent closes.
public class FormModelCollection: Form { }

If a user tries to close this form, it simply hides itself and can be unhidden using a button on the MDI parent.

Here is what I don't understand. When clicking a row (as in the screenshot above), a new child gets created, but remains in the background even after the following:
var form = new FormModel(this);

form.Show();
form.Focus();
form.Activate();
form.BringToFront();

Please note that the reference to this is the MDI parent since the code is executed by the parent.
Now, I understand that something may be wrong in the way I trigger the row double click. BUT notice in the screenshot that when the NEW button is clicked on the MDI Parent, the same code above produces the same result. I have not programmed the culprit form in any special way except to hide when closed.
Any advice would be appreciated. I am happy to elaborate further.

What is FormModel? Shouldn't it be the FormModelEditor type you mentioned? I don't see you setting its MdiParent property to this. When you do this: var form = new FormModel(this);, you set the Owner, not the MDIParent, of course -- What is special about the FormModelCollection type? -- Note that MdiChild Forms are not exactly parented to the MDIForm, but the MDIClient container, the dark grey-ish object that covers the background of the MDIForm. Everything that stays on top of the MDIClient (i.e., it's not part of that hierarchy), also stays on top of any MDI child Form

I tried to recreate the problem, but the new form keeps the focus. Maybe you can look at or try the following code to see how it differs from your code.
[STAThread]
public static void Main(String[] args) {
    Application.SetCompatibleTextRenderingDefault( false );
    Application.EnableVisualStyles();

    Form f2 = new Form();
    f2.Size = new Size(800,800);
    f2.IsMdiContainer = true;
    FlowLayoutPanel p = new FlowLayoutPanel { Dock = DockStyle.Top, AutoSize = true, AutoSizeMode = System.Windows.Forms.AutoSizeMode.GrowAndShrink };
    Button btnNew = new Button { Text = "New", AutoSize = true, AutoSizeMode = System.Windows.Forms.AutoSizeMode.GrowAndShrink };
    p.Controls.Add(btnNew);
    f2.Controls.Add(p);
    Action<Object, EventArgs> newForm = null;
    newForm = (o3, e3) => {
        Form f3 = new Form();
        if (f2.MdiChildren.Length == 0) {
            DataGridView dgv = new DataGridView { AllowUserToAddRows = false, Dock = DockStyle.Fill };
            dgv.Columns.Add("Column1", "Column1");
            dgv.Rows.Add("A");
            dgv.CellDoubleClick += new DataGridViewCellEventHandler(newForm);
            f3.Controls.Add(dgv);
        }

        f3.Size = new Size(400, 400);
        f3.MdiParent = f2;
        f3.Show();
    };
    btnNew.Click += new EventHandler(newForm);
    Application.Run(f2);
}

